# Check if record exists - performance

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, t-sql, select

I have a table that will contain large amounts of data. The purpose of this table is user transactions.

I will be inserting into this table from a web-service, which a third party will be calling, frequently.

The third party will be supplying a reference code (most probably a string).

The requirement here is that I will need to check whether this reference code has already been inserted. If it exists, just return the details and do nothing else. If it doesn't create the transaction as expected. The reasoning behind this is the possibility of loss of communication with the service after the request is received.

I have some performance concerns with this, as the search will be done on a string value, and also on a large table. Most of the time the transaction will not exist in the database, as this is just a precaution.

I am not asking for code here, but for the best approach for performance.

Comment: Is an index on that column? Also, which transaction level are you using? You could enable [`READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) to releases shared locks as quickly as possible.

Comment: There will be, this is a completely new project with a new DB. I am open to anything at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

AS your subject indicates if you are trying to look for evaluating EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Sometable) then there will not be much of performance penality. This is because you will not be writing just a bunch of 1s (means the inner query) to evaluate the result to boolean.

Other aspect to this is the non clustered indexing provided on the reference code field.If the length of the reference code lets say its a fixed length string (CHAR(50) then also the B -tree will be optimum .

I am not sure about the data consistency requirements hence exepct the normal readcommitted will wont do any harm unless you have highly transnational read writes.

Comment: I know that exists is efficient as it stops on the first result it finds. But as I said, most of the time, the transaction will not be there, so the select exists will be going through the whole table anyway.

We are calculating around 15-30 writes a second.

Comment: I hope you are talking about the table size to be around 1 -2 million rows anything above you will see significant difference in performance mostly it attributes to how the table is designed. How many data got squeezed into extends and pages, fragmentation due to modifications, file io etc. Those are the issues to address soon after the table grows to a high value.

Comment: Actually, tables will be created for each month to reduce the table size. It will eventually be around 1-2 million rows per month.

Comment: Thats a good strategy and i presume you will be having identity seeds on primary key to reduce index fragmentation. Also do look at horizontal partitioning of data and move table to different file group if it has huge growth compared to rest of the tables which will help later in implementing optimised backup strategy and improve file io if on SAN or using RAID

Comment: Will have identity seeds yes. I considered doing horizontal partitioning as well as the tables will be quite large in that respect too.